Is there some standard notification system allowing to include links?
There is notify-send --app-name="app name" "summary" "body body body https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask" but it shows pop up that does not allow even copying text.
And forget about ability to have working link to website or filesystem location.
Is there any standard way to do this? Or would I need to implement own GUI for that?
lsb_release -a shows
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal



I’m voting to close this question because it's a rant rather than a serious attempt at a question

That is a genuine question not a rant. If such standard tool does not exist then it is also a valid answer.

have you tried wrapping  a href around it? or using BB Code?

@Rinzwind not yet! Looks like a fitting answer!

@graham And it turns out that it has an answer! And as seen rant would be really premature here.

@mook765 has reported this as working for them on 22.04.4 / Plasma, and @Rinzwind has reported this as working on Cinnamon and Budgie.
Looking at the oldest Desktop Notifications Specification I could find (Version 0.3), on the Markup section, the following is reported:

Body text may contain markup. The markup is XML-based, and consists of
a small subset of HTML along with a few additional tags.
The following tags should be supported by the notification server.
Though it is optional, it is recommended. Notification servers that do
not support these tags should filter them out.










<b> ... </b>
Bold


<i> ... </i>
Italic


<u> ... </u>
Underline


<a href="..."> ... </a>
Hyperlink



So you may try:
notify-send --app-name="app name" "summary" 'body body body <a href="https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask">Ask</a>'

However, on 22.04 / GNOME + notify-send 0.7.9, this kinda works out of the box for me (without the need of any tag, this is what happens if I run notify-send --app-name="app name" "summary" "body body body https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask" in the terminal):

user@[REDACTED] ~ % lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
user@[REDACTED] ~ % notify-send -v
notify-send 0.7.9

So, if the first method doesn't work for you for some reason, you can still try and update (at the very least this will work on GNOME).
I'm not sure where in the stack something has changed over time that has enabled this.
The first method doesn't work for links on my end (the other tags are still correctly processed), but this might be due to this "automatic parser" that has been introduced sitting in between the invocation of notify-send and the spec-following parser.

It may depend on the desktop environment, for me the suggested command works on Plasma desktop on 22.04.4

I tested this: all tags with the exception of <a> go through, and the markup is applied. So it may be the case that the "automatic parser" is replacing the link with a correctly formatted <a> tag, which once is processed by the spec-following parser appears as a valid <a> tag nested inside an outer <a> tag, which makes the outer tag invalid, which in turn has the parser spit out a correctly formatted and clickable link surrounded by the invalid, unprocessed <a> tag.

@mook765 Which suggested command? Mine or OP's? And in any case, what if you try the other one? Maybe we can figure this out by elimination.

It's the command suggested by you which works for me, the command OP suggested does not work, producing only the notification box with plain text like OP showed.

@mook765 Thanks! So it might be the case that something in the GNOME stack is doing the parsing (annoying, as one would have to figure out how to trick the parser into somehow letting trough custom links)

Maybe it works in the same way as here on AskUbuntu, something like [custom text](URI), I"m not on Gnome, so I can't try. But that's what I would try out first.

@mook765 Good call, I fogot to mention, neither BB tags nor Markdown work unfortunately.

excelllent @kos "a href" also works in Ubuntu cinnamon, Budgie

And filesystem links are also working!

@reducingactivity You mean you can href a local file? That's kinda cool, good to know! I'm glad it worked out!

@kos  yes! notify-send --app-name="app name" "summary" 'body body body <a href="file:/media">Ask</a>' also works

that smells like a security hole :D  don't tell me you can add a script tag and add a js file :X

I expect that JS file would open in text editor. Though I guess that one could make html file? But anyway program with access to create notifications can also simply delete file or make internet connections anyway....

@reducingactivity I think that Rinzwind is mostly joking, but the hint is at the fact that if a script tag containing some inline Javascript was processed by the parser, than you could have the parser execute whatever JS code you want with the privileges of the parser, perhaps more elevated than your user's

that's how I read it at least but you should ask @Rinzwind :)

It opens as a text file in your editor set for js so no worries there :)
